# NGINX 403 Forbidden at Root

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Setting up a site on AWS Lightsail using the Linux/NGINX install from Bitnami.

The root folder (/opt/bitnami/nginx/html) contains **index.html** as default, everything runs just fine. However, swapping that index file out for **index.php** returns 403 in chrome and logs the following error...

```
*42 directory index of "/opt/bitnami/nginx/html/" is forbidden
```

Index.php is executing just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Index.php is accessible in the browser by pointing to its path directly (site.com/index.php)

The contents of my config file **nginx.conf** are unmodified and as follow...

```
user  daemon daemon;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";

events {
    use                 epoll;
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept        on;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

    access_log  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log";

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types text/plain
               text/xml
               text/css
               text/javascript
               application/json
               application/javascript
               application/x-javascript
               application/ecmascript
               application/xml
               application/rss+xml
               application/atom+xml
               application/rdf+xml
               application/xml+rss
               application/xhtml+xml
               application/x-font-ttf
               application/x-font-opentype
               application/vnd.ms-fontobject
               image/svg+xml
               image/x-icon
               application/atom_xml;

    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf";

}
```

the contents of the include "**/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf**" are as follows...

```
# HTTP server

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

}
```

the contents of the include "**/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf**" are as follows...

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Note: I also tried adding `index    index.php` to the above.
Any ideas as to what might be going on here?

**NOTE:** Troubleshooting, i tried a stripped alternative to the **nginx.config** file referenced above, which resolved the 403 error but wouldn't do anything other than download the index.php file when visiting the root...

```
user  daemon daemon;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";



events {
    use                 epoll;
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept        on;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

    access_log  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log";

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by updating "**/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf**" as follows...

```
location / {
    root   html;
    index  index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Not my proudest moment, i'll admit.